# Why does writing to file increase cache-misses and branch-misses so much?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, perf

Following is the code I am profiling:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define N 10000

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("log.txt");

    int A[N], B[N], C[N];

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        A[i] = B[i] = i;
    }   

    int sum = 0;

    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
        C[j] = A[j]+B[j];
        //fout<<C[j]<<endl;
        sum += C[j];
        sum %= 103;
    }

    cout<<sum<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Following is the profiling command:

```
perf stat -e instructions:u -e instructions:k -e cache-misses -e page-faults -e branch-misses ./test
```

Output is:

```
Performance counter stats for './test':

 15,60,186      instructions:u           
  8,35,753      instructions:k           
    24,345      cache-misses                                                
       123      page-faults                                                 
    13,051      branch-misses                                               

 0.001327182 seconds time elapsed
```

However, when I uncomment that single commented line, I get the following output:

```
Performance counter stats for './test':

         75,72,868      instructions:u           
      12,29,31,625      instructions:k           
          2,18,333      cache-misses                                                
               121      page-faults                                                 
            73,662      branch-misses                                               

       0.525844017 seconds time elapsed
```

I am not able to understand what is causing such a huge increase in cache-misses and moderately high increase in branch-misses. Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Well there is probably a branch in `fout << ...` and most likely calling `fout` will introduce cache misses as you have to go deal with `fout` and then go back to the arrays so you keep swapping back and forth.

Answer (score 4):

Without the "`fout<<C[j]<<endl;`" line your program is mostly running in user space (I'd rather say, the significant part of your program is *entirely* running in user space). By uncommenting that line (which is inside a loop) you introduce a lot of additional system calls (this is shown by huge increase of the `instructions:k` number reported by the profiler). System calls are expensive since they involve a context switch which, depending on the hardware architecture and the OS, may invalidate a noticeable part of the CPU cache.

Note that the main culprit here is `endl` (which forces flushing the buffers and thus triggers a system call). Replace it with `'\n'` and the impact on the performance should be much less.